# Python 3.2.1: Converting Entry to Number

Tags: python, graphics, numbers

I am, on my own, trying to create somewhat of a Python "The Price is Right". My problem is, I'm trying to convert the Entry to a number. See the code below:

```
 ...

 Podium1Bid = Entry(Point(42.5, 35), 4)
Podium2Bid = Entry(Point(122.5, 35), 4)
Podium3Bid = Entry(Point(202.5, 35), 4)
Podium4Bid = Entry(Point(282.5, 35), 4)

Bid1 = int(Podium1Bid.getText())
Bid2 = int(Podium2Bid.getText())
Bid3 = int(Podium3Bid.getText())
Bid4 = int(Podium4Bid.getText())

 ...
```

The lines Bid1 = int(Podium1Bid.getText()), etc. through Bid4... give me the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
       ContestantsRow()
    File "<pyshell#7>", line 31, in ContestantsRow
       Bid1 = int(Podium1Bid.getText())
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I have also tried using eval() and similar things, and I still get errors.

Comment: Have you checked what `Podium1Bid.getText()` actually returns?

Comment: @Lycha: When I enter random numerical values to test (133, 123, 456, 789), it prints those out (I commented out the int(Podium1Bid.getText()) etc. along with a few other lines). And if I have it comparing the value of Podium1Bid.getText() to a number value (later in the code), of course it says it can only compare numbers, not 'Text'.

Comment: Can you post your code for the Entry class (and the Point class if it is the source of the integer value)?  Also, show what integer you expect out for a given input.

Comment: @Raymond Hettinger: I am just using the import graphics to get the Python Graphics library (which I do have on my machine).

Comment: Okay, I expanded the answer to include the case where you don't have control over the class (i.e. you can't add __int__).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what's going on here with these `PodiumBid` objects, but the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

simply means python doesn't know how to convert an empty string to a number.  `int('')` will raise the same exception.

If your intend for an empty string to be equal to `0`, you can do something like this:

```
int(mystring or 0)
```

which will use `0` as the input for `int` if `mystring` evaluates to `False` (such as empty strings).

Answer (score 3):

If *Point* and *Entry* were your own classes, you could ddd an __int__ method to your *Entry* class.  That will teach the class how to be convertible to an integer.

In the case of the Python Graphics Library, you should inspect the objects using `vars(Podium1Bid)` to see which attributes are directly accessible with something like `Podium1Bid.width` or `Podium1Bid.point.x`.